# I'm trying to print an array in java and I need to use both the public void intArray() as a method

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print the values while still using String[] and public void intArray

I've tried moving stuff around and using set and get methods but they don't work

```
public void intArray()
  {
    //create an int array called num that will store 4 elements
    int[] num = {32,26,19,40};
    //assign 32 to index 0  
    //assign 26 to index 1 
    //assign 19 to index 2  
    //assign 40 to index 3 
    //change index 3 to 57
    num[3] = 57;
  }
  //write a line of code to print length of array:  Length of array of :  
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    System.out.println("The length of the array is " + num.length);
    //write a line of code to print index 3:  Index 3 is :    
    System.out.println("Index three is " + num[3]);
    //create a for loop to loop through and print all elements in the array
    for(int element: num)
    {
      System.out.println(element);
    }
  }
```

I'm expecting to get the printed stuff (the num length, the 3rd index, and the element), but they don't print. I need to use intArray() to store at least int[] num = {32,26,19,40}; and num[3] = 57;

Comment: What, *specifically*, does "its not coming along" mean?  What did you expect, and what happened instead?

Comment: Does the assignment require `intArray()` to have a void return type?

Comment: Unclear if you need to use `String[]args` or your own string array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you are trying to achieve something like that:

```
public class MainClass {

  public static int[] intArray() {
    //create an int array called num that will store 4 elements
    int[] num = {32,26,19,40};
    //assign 32 to index 0
    //assign 26 to index 1
    //assign 19 to index 2
    //assign 40 to index 3
    //change index 3 to 57
    num[3] = 57;
    return num;
  }
  //write a line of code to print length of array:  Length of array of :
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    int[] num = intArray();

    System.out.println("The length of the array is " + num.length);
    //write a line of code to print index 3:  Index 3 is :
    System.out.println("Index three is " + num[3]);
    //create a for loop to loop through and print all elements in the array
    for(int element: num) {
      System.out.println(element);
    }
  }
}
```

`int[] num` was invisible due to it was local in `intArray()` method. For calling `intArray()` from `static void main` the `intArray()` either should be static as well as `main` or should be called by creating a new instance of MainClass: `int[] num = new MainClass().intArray();`

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the num variable is inside the intArray() method so not visible in your main method. You can change the signature of the intArray method to return the created array:

```
public static int[] intArray()
{
    //create an int array called num that will store 4 elements
    int[] num = {32,26,19,40};
    num[3] = 57;
    return num;
}
```

I've also changed intArrray to be static so it is callable from within main.
In your main you can start by calling intArray and store the result in a variable visible within main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] mainNum=intArray();
    // now you can check the size or index 3 using this mainNum variable
}
```

I've used a different name `mainNum` so it is clear what the scope is of num and mainNum.